# Errors while trying to write joint likelihood of a normal_lpdf and a bernoulli_lpmf in Stan

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am trying to calculate Bayes Factor using the package `bridgesampling` in R. For this I am trying to fit the model in `Stan`. It is a hierarchical model with the Alternative (Hypothesis) model having parameters `beta, gamma1, gamma3 & sigma`.

Please find the model below:

```css
stanmodelH1 = 'data {
 int<lower=0> n;
 int<lower=0> k;
 vector[n] y;
 int x1[n];
 real<lower=0> a;
 real<lower=0> b;
 matrix[n, k] G;
 matrix[n, k+1] X1;
 matrix[n, 2] x;
}

parameters {
 vector[2] beta;
 vector[k+1] gamma3;
 vector[k] gamma1;
 real<lower=0> sigma;
}

model {
 target += inv_gamma_lpdf(sigma | a, b);
 target += normal_lpdf(gamma1 | 0, sqrt(1.1));
 target += normal_lpdf(gamma3 | 0, 1);
 target += normal_lpdf(beta | 0, sqrt(1.2));
  target += normal_lpdf(y | x*beta + G*gamma1, sqrt(sigma)) + bernoulli_lpmf(x1 | Phi(X1*gamma3));
  
  //these two _lpdf and _lpmf should be added and not multiplied. This is the answer.
}
'
```

and the corresponding `rstan` code:

```css
stanfitmodelH1 = sampling(stanmodelH1, data = list(n = n, k = k, y = y, x1 = x1, 
                                                   a = 4, b = 3, G = G, X1 = X1, x = x),
                          iter = 50000, warmup = 20000, chains = 3, cores = 3,
                          control = list(adapt_delta = 0.99, max_treedepth = 15))
```

Now, when I sample from this model in `Stan`; it throws the following errors:

```css
Warning messages:
1: There were 205 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.99 may help. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup 
2: There were 3 chains where the estimated Bayesian Fraction of Missing Information was low. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#bfmi-low 
3: Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems
```

**Please note that**, *similar errors are thrown when sampling from the null model.* Where basically `beta = beta0 = c(rnorm(1), 0)` and `gamma3 = rep(0, k+1)` in contrast to the no-restriction in the alternate model.

These are clearly some random errors occurring due to some (I do not know what and I really want to find out) sampling problems in `Stan`. I know this because I ran the model (and the null model as well) several times without the following part: `bernoulli_lpmf(x1 | Phi(X1*gamma3))` in the last line of the `Stan` model and modifying the data block of the code accordingly and then it returned no warnings or errors. But, this will not solve my purpose. Because, my hypothesis involves both `beta & gamma3` and the above portion clearly adds the `gamma3`.

As a result of the errors in `Stan`, the function `bridge_sampler` from the `R` package `bridgesampling` is returning the following errors:

```css
> H1.bridge = bridge_sampler(stanfitmodelH1, silent = TRUE)
Error in while (i <= maxiter && criterion_val > tol) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
2744 of the 45000 log_prob() evaluations on the proposal draws produced -Inf/Inf.
```

*Also note that,* these errors (from `bridge_sampler`) are not thrown when there are no errors from `Stan`. e.g., the case where the model is run without the `bernoulli_lpmf(x1 | Phi(X1*gamma3))` part.

I tried to best explain my problem. Please ask me should any more clarification is needed.

*Could someone please identify where exactly the error(s) is/are occurring?*

**Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: Those **warning messages** (divergent transitions, low BFMI) are telling you that Stan cannot sample from the posterior distribution you defined with adequate efficiency. Thus, the results are meaningless and you need to overcome that before even thinking about computing Bayes Factors. I find it hard to believe you really wanted to multiply the logarithm of a normal likelihood by the logarithm of a Bernoulli likelihood. Did you mean to add them instead of multiplying them?

Comment: @BenGoodrich Exactly Sir! I myself am startled that I missed that all along! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake all along! As pointed out by [Ben Goodrich Sir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762912/ben-goodrich) the logarithms should be added instead of being multiplied as they are in the logarithmic scale. A very silly mistake from my side! I will edit the question with the correct code! **Thanks to you all!**